# Swiper - moving slides

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I'm using Swiper plugin from https://idangero.us/swiper/api/.
I have 20 items in Swiper, 10 items per slide in two rows.

[image]

When I click in pagination bullet next to active bullet, it moves only one column of items to the right. I need to have two bullets only in pagination, so how to set moving 10 items per one slide?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  new Swiper(".clients-swiper-container", {
      pagination: ".swiper-pagination-clients",

      paginationClickable: true,
      slideToClickedSlide: true,
      slidesPerView: 5,
      slidesPerColumn: 2,
      spaceBetween: 20,
      nextButton: ".swiper-button-next3",
      prevButton: ".swiper-button-prev3"
  })
})
```

Comment: Please provide a working example in the questions it would be better to understand the question

Comment: please, look now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add property to your JS:

```
slidesPerGroup: 5,
```

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dinty/0uwyzdse/5/